# How to follow up a less priority task?

Tags: follow-up

My supervisor has told me that he'll provide me with whatever I need for learning at work. So I asked him for a virtual machine that has some applications I need be installed on, around a month and a week ago. I followed up it three weeks ago and he immediately went to the responsible person (a very very busy one) and asked him to prepare that. But I've heard nothing back so far. I know they are too busy to do fewer priority tasks soon, but I also need to have that to fill up the gaps among my tasks with learning. What is the best way and when is the proper time to follow up that without being looked so hassling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way and when is the proper time to follow up that without being looked so hassling.

**I'd say that you should follow up right now,** and in frequent intervals. To be honest, one month is a lot of time to wait for something like that, as any "less priority" task can become more critical as time passes by.

You may consider **asking first that busy person that was to provide you with the VM**. Chances are that he may already have it ready but forgot to tell you. A simple *"Hey Joe, wanted to know how are you going with that Virtual Machine I require?"*, should suffice; also I think it is better if you go to his office and do this in person for a swifter response.

If he still does not have the machine ready and there seems no clear moment when it will, then proceed to follow up with your boss and ask for indications. He can then handle this situation as he seems fit, or perhaps assign someone else to provide you with the machine.

Comment: Helpful answer, thank you. Though it's easier for me to follow up that with my boss than that guy.

Comment: I just don't know what to tell my boss to not seem rude or bothering, maybe mostly the problem with being non-native English speaker.

Comment: @Verver: Just a suggestion, if your boss is really this busy then you'd be doing him/her a big favor by working with the person responsible for installing the VM directly.

Comment: Actually that responsible person is more busy :) I can reach out my boss easier

Answer (score 1):

If you can figure out how to install it yourself, then go to the responsible person and kindly ask for the software.  Tell them that you know they are really busy so if they could just point you in the right direction you'll take care of it.

If you can't, then possibly the best way would be to check in with this person once each morning to see if they can take care of it.  After a couple days of asking I'm sure they'll find the time.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't have the authority to do that myself but yeah I will check in with my boss for that